# couldn't filter request through middleware

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-middleware

I am trying to filter my http request by using middleware. 
I want to check if the **"friends_id"** that i am getting from http request and **"my_id"** that I am passing in through Auth already don't exists in the same row, If they do I wanna redirect to home page and if they don't I wanna execute the normal request which will eventually insert the data that I am checking for

The error is **"Trying to get property 'friends_id' of non-object "**

**Here's my "Friends" middleware:-**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class Friends
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {  $auth = Auth()->user()->id;
        $dost = $request->friends_id;

        $ip = DB::table('friends')
   ->where('my_id', '=', $auth)
        ->where('friends_id', '=', $dost)
        ->get();

   if($ip->friends_id != $dost){
        return $next($request);
    }


return redirect('/home');

    }
}
```

**Here's my friends Table:-**

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('friends', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
        $table->string('my_id');
        $table->string('friends_id');
        $table->string('name');     
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**This is my Route:-**

```
Route::post('/f', 'FriendsController@store')->middleware('friends');
```

*-ThankYou*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The Solution is:-*

**Friends Middleware:-**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (auth()->check()) {
            $ip = DB::table('friends')->where('my_id', '=', auth()->id())->where('friends_id', '=', $request->friends_id)->first();

            if ($ip && $ip->friends_id == $request->friends_id) {
                return redirect('/home');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try this**

*your query will be wrong use `where` instead of `whereColumn` and when you get first record use only `first()` not `get()`*

```
 use DB;

 $ip = DB::table('friends')
       ->select('my_id', 'friends_id')
       ->where([['my_id', '=', '$auth'],['friends_id', '=', '$dost']])
       ->first();
```

**EDIT**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{  
    $auth = Auth()->user()->id;
    $dost = $request->friends_id;

    $ip = DB::table('friends')
       ->select('my_id', 'friends_id')
       ->where([['my_id', '=', '$auth'],['friends_id', '=', '$dost']])
       ->first();

    if($ip->friends_id == $dost){
        return redirect('/home');
    } else {
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: A answer might be more helpfull if you explain why the above would work.

Comment: Ok your query will be wrong use `where`  istead of `whereColumn` and when you get first record use only `first()` not `get()` that's it.....

Comment: @vikas katariya I am getting this error **"Trying to get property 'friends_id' of non-object "**

Comment: @vikas katariya **"Trying to access array offset on value of type null"** this is the current error

Comment: ` if($ip->friends_id == $dost){
        return redirect('/home');
    } else {
        return $next($request);
    }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214646/discussion-between-vikas-katariya-and-anonymous-chatbox).